# adding previous/next slide event listeners for modal lightbox (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm building a portfolio site for a friend which displays paintings. All paitings are displayed on the index page, and I've created a for loop so that click on each painting opens up modal displaying that painting:

```
// create references to the modal...
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// to all images -- note I'm using a class!
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
// the image in the modal
const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
// and the caption in the modal
const captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


// Go through all of the images with our custom class
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.addEventListener("click", openModal)
}

// Function to open modal
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

I've attached previous and next buttons to the modal, and I'd like to be able to go back and forth between paintings once the modal is open:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times; 
  </span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>

  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add event listeners to the prev/next buttons however am running into trouble - I'm not sure how to access the selected image from the modal so it knows to open the previous/next one when prev/next buttons are clicked.

```
// selecting the prev and next buttons
const prev = document.querySelector(".prev")
const next = document.querySelector(".next")

prev.addEventListener("click", previousSlide);

function previousSlide() {
  // Not sure what to put here...
}
```

Can anyone help me out or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: jsFiddle or working example would really help, I see you query some elements by class names but in your provided HTML there are no such classes, so to help you more specifically, more correct working example would be good.

Comment: Hi Erasmus, thanks for the suggestion. The solutuon posted below guessed the classes correctly, however I'll make sure to make my examples clearer in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Do be able to found the previous and/or next image you need to know on what image you are. I propose to do that by passing the index of the image to `openModal` and "saving" it using [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

Once this is done, when one click on `.prev` ou `.next` you only need to add or remove 1 to the index and call `openModal`

In the snippet below I've tried to "guess" what was the missing HTML and CSS

```js
// create references to the modal...
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// to all images -- note I'm using a class!
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
// the image in the modal
const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
// and the caption in the modal
const captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


// Go through all of the images with our custom class
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.addEventListener("click", event => {
    openModal(i)
  });
}

// Function to open modal
function openModal(index) {
  console.log('index', index);
  modal.dataset.index = index;
  modal.classList.add("open");
  modalImg.src = images[index].src;
  captionText.innerHTML = images[index].alt;
}

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener('click', event => {
  const index = modal.dataset.index === '0' ? images.length - 1 : +modal.dataset.index - 1
  openModal(index);
})
document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', event => {
  openModal((+modal.dataset.index + 1) % images.length);
})
```

```css
#myModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  place-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8e8e880;
}

#myModal.open {
  display: grid;
}

.prev,
.next,
.close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prev {
  left: 20px;
}

.next {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=5" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=6" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=7" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=8" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=9" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=10" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=11" alt="" class="myImages">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=12" alt="" class="myImages">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').classList.remove('open')">&times; 
  </span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>

  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Hadn't come across the dataset property before - it's super handy!